# Order List count 2 and 3 with respect to modulus 4

Tags: c#, list

I have a list which I need to sort into an order provided it contains ALL of the numbers in its sequence:

Manually just setting them does not seem like the way to go about it.

I know how to order lists to be ascending or descending but having the modulus 4 is sending my head funny.

Modulus of 4 is due to this being linked to node neighbours on a grid

I do not know what order they are put into the list initially as it is random and changes every time - Procedural generation of grid connections

I do not want a new list, I just want to simply re-arrange the current one.

List Count of 3:

0, 1, 2

1, 2, 3

2, 3, 0

3, 0, 1

```
if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(0) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(1) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(2)) // Top-Right-Down
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 0;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 1;
      acceptedIndicies[2] = 2;
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(1) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(2) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(3)) // Right-Down-Left
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 1;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 2;
      acceptedIndicies[2] = 3;   
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(2) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(3) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(0)) // Down-Left-Top
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 2;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 3;
      acceptedIndicies[2] = 0;
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(3) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(0) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(1)) // Left-Top-Right
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 3;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 0;
      acceptedIndicies[2] = 1;
}
```

List Count of 2:

0, 1

1, 2

2, 3

3, 0

```
if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(0) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(1))                 
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 0;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 1;        
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(1) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(2))
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 1;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 2;
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(2) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(3))
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 2;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 3;
}
else if (acceptedIndicies.Contains(3) && acceptedIndicies.Contains(0))
{
      // Order List in the sequence
      acceptedIndicies[0] = 3;
      acceptedIndicies[1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: C# if you could please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Build a valid modulus sequence. That's easy:

   ```
    var modulusSequence = Enumerable.Range(0, modulus);
   ```
2. Now you need a way of generating all valid modulus sequences of a given modulus and length. Thats easy too, just shift left or right a total of `modulus` times a valid sequence we happen to know taking the first *n* elements of every new shifted sequence:

   ```
   private static IEnumerable<int> ShiftLeft(IEnumerable<int> sequence)
   {
       if (!sequence.Any())
           yield break;

       foreach (var i in sequence.Skip(1))
       {
           yield return i;
       }

       yield return sequence.First();
   }

   private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> getAllModulusSequences(int modulus, int length)
   {
       var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, modulus);

       for (var i = 0; i < modulus; i++)
       {
           yield return sequence.Take(length);
           sequence = ShiftLeft(sequence);
       }
   }
   ```
3. And now you simply have to check if the given sequence contains all elements of a valid sequence (note that doing it the way around is not correct because you could get false positives if the given sequence has repeating items). If it does, return the valid sequence.

   I do note that I'm not ordering your list, I'm returning a new one or `null` if the sequence is not valid.

   ```
   public static IList<int> GetOrderedSequence(IList<int> sequence, int modulus)
   {
       if (modulus < sequence.Count)
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(sequence), "Sequence can not contain more elements than specified modulus.");

       foreach (var validSequence in getAllModulusSequences(modulus, sequence.Count))
       {
           if (validSequence.All(item => sequence.Contains(item)))
               return validSequence.ToList();
       }

       return null;
   }
   ```

Is this faster / more efficient than your approach? Probably not. Is it prettier? I think so but its debatable. Is it more flexible? Oh yes!

If you are absolutely sure you are only going to need to check `2` and `3` long sequences with modulus `4` then you could keep your code. If not, implement a general purpose solution like the one I've shown you.

Comment: That's great! Makes perfect sense, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you ever so much.

Comment: @DannyFox you' re welcome! I originally wrote this on my cell phone so I've refactored the code a little to make it cleaner.